# Search a word from a paragraph using solr

Tags: php, solr

I set description as field in solr.. Now i want to get description by searching a single word

in it.. How is it possible using php solr?

Please specify solr query for search..

someone plz help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use a word in paragraph you could do this:-

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" >
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It will be more flexible if you can index your data with the [NGramTokenizerFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/NGramTokenizerFactory.html) to do complete front and back wildcard searches. If you just want to search for substrings at the beginning or end of the string, consider using the [EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory.html).

Comment: Can you specify the query for searching a word in description using solr?